# According to the Catholic church everyone has a Guardian Angel,but what happens when you get married?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, guardian-angels

The two becomes one .How does this change anything if anything for the Angel?

Mark
…7‘For this reason a man will leave his father and mother and be united to his wife, 8and the two will become one flesh.’ So they are no longer two, but one flesh. 9Therefore what God has joined together, let man not separate.”

Comment: Your question is badly written.  Put more thought and effort into your questions.  "How does this change anything if anything for an Angel" is bad writing, and reflects lack of  effort.  Please edit your question so that it is better written.  While some folks will edit, it would be appreciated if you would put more effort and thought into forming your questions (some of which are intriguing).  My down vote is for your habit of low effort and low quality questions (some of which have, with work and editing and comments, been worth the effort, some not).  Put in the effort.

Comment: [An example of a question where someone put in some effort](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/19316/24204).  Please learn from that example.  See also ["well asked questions"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you asking: "Do married couples get another guardian angel when they marry?"

Comment: @Geremia I dunno what it looks like.Maybe they get another Angel extra or a greater angel to defend them I dunno

Answer (score 2):

Your question is answered in the text of its asking.

> According to the Catholic church everyone has a Guardian Angel.

That is correct. (CCC 334-336)

#### Two persons, one marriage

> What happens when you get married?

Per the scripture you quoted "two become one flesh."  That uniting during the sacrament of marriage is something that happens on earth, between two persons, unified beings that are both spiritual and corporeal.<sup>1</sup>  Angels are beings of spirit.  There is no reason to presume that they are affected by that, nor that their guardian role does not remain to be fulfilled.

When the Bible says married couples “become one flesh,” that is a way of saying that (1) there is a level of carnal intimacy that is only possible in a marriage, and (2) therefore, the marriage union is indissoluble. (Catholic PoV)<sup>2</sup>.   It does not mean that the man and woman cease to be two distinct persons.  Each person has their guardian angel.

Angels as beings of spirit, [per my reply to **your** recent question here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52732/24204) 
(CCC 329)

> 'Angel' is the name of their office, not of their nature. If you seek
>   the name of their nature, it is 'spirit'; if you seek the name of
>   their office, it is 'angel': from what they are, 'spirit', from what
>   they do, 'angel.'"

According to Catholic belief (and indeed, a lot of Christian belief) the flesh and the spirit are two domains that overlap (or are as above, *unified*) during a person's life here on earth.  The flesh in time ends, at death, whereas the spirit is eternal.

---

<sup>1,</sup><sup>2</sup> Assistance in how to phrase this from @AthanasiusOfAlex

Comment: The philosophy professor in me is speaking now :). I don’t think it is entirely accurate to say that we are “made up” of body and spirit. It would be better to say that we are unified beings that are _both_ spiritual _and_ corporeal. (The relationship of the soul to the body is that the soul _informs_ the body—i.e., it makes the body what it is.) Otherwise, we would fall into Cartesian dualism—as if we were two “blocks”—spirit and matter—united accidentally. (Descartes even thought the point of union was the pineal gland....)

Comment: Anyway, you might want to say that when the Bible says married couples “become one flesh,” that is a metaphorical way of saying that (1) there is a level of carnal intimacy that is only possible in a marriage, and (2) therefore, the marriage union is indissoluble. It does not mean, in any way, that the man and woman cease to be two distinct _persons_.

Comment: @AthanasiusOfAlex *Grazie Mille*

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there are references to this as it is essentially a nonsequiter in the church.  Two become one as in the decisions you make now affect both, as if you were one entity.  You don't literally morph into a single body and become one being.

So if you hold to the Catholic belief that a guardian angel is an angel (a created, non-human, non-corporeal being) that has been assigned to guard a particular person, especially with respect to helping that person avoid spiritual dangers and achieve salvation, then that angel may also help the person avoid physical dangers, particularly if this will help the person achieve salvation.  This implys that you as a physical being that is still a separate physical being would still benefit from your own "personal" guardian angel.

http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/para/336.htm

> "From its beginning until death, human life is surrounded by their watchful care and intercession. Beside each believer stands an angel as protector and shepherd leading him to life. Already here on earth the Christian life shares by faith in the blessed company of angels and men united in God [CCC 336]."

If one person "lost" their guardian angel then what happens if you get divorced?  You still are one flesh if it wasn't a biblical reason for divorce, so does one person get the one Angel in the divorce and the other loses theirs?